# How to implement a subclass of basestring in python

Tags: python

I'm using Python2.7. I want to implement a class 'URL' that behaves just like basestring, except that this class can do some extra things like 'remove query in the url' in the **init** function. The final code should be like this:

```
url_string = 'http://example.com?query=q'
if not isinstance(url_string, URL):
    url_string = URL(url_string)
print url_string
```

The expected result is 'http://example.com'.
I don't know which functions should be overwrite, or is there an alternative method to implement this.

Comment: Leaving aside for one moment the question as expressed, why not use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) for this?

Comment: As far as the actual question: have you tried `class URL(basestring):`? What problems did you have?

Comment: @two-Bit Thanks for your comment. I have types like `str` to convert other fields, say, 'numbers', so I want to make a uniform way to do this. It seems that `class URL(basestring):` will break the code.